# Display a text block with Qt like an CSS inline-block

Tags: html, css, qt

With HTML and CSS I can display text with `inline-block` so:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .inline { 
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='inline'><div>aaa1<br/>a2<br/>aaaa3</div></div>
    <div class='inline'><div>bb1<br/>bbbb2</div></div>
    <div class='inline'><div>c1<br/>cccc2<br/>cc3<br/>ccc4</div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can run it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0pxajf9/) to displaying.

Is it possible to get the same display result using Qt (without `QtWebView`, `QtWebEngine`, `QtWebKit` and `QTextTable`) with the ability of selecting text as in a browser? And with a moving of the blocks to the next line as a word wrap when is many blocks in a single line. Blocks can be of different widths depending on the length of words included in them.

The result of the displaying and the selection of the text for me is important. If this could be done through HTML or other tags, it would be good, but it does not matter.

Comment: `QTextEdit` supports basic HTML, but I'm not sure if this is supported.

Comment: Look the [qt html subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) to see if you can.

Comment: I edited the question about the HTML tags.

Comment: Have you tried `QLabel`, or `QTextEdit` (or `QTextBrowser`)? How does it look with them? I'm sure it is possible with them, not sure how much you need to change the HTML to make it work, or if you need to do it somehow otherwise than HTML-like rich text, though.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#using-qtextedit-as-a-display-widget

Comment: `QTextEdit` displays as `display: block;` instead `display: inline-block;`